# How to keep columns after `summarise` operation in `dplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this type of data:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Acer laurinum", "Acer laurinum Hassk.", "Acmella paniculata", 
                          "Adinandra cf. integerrima", "Adinandra cf. integerrima T.Anderson"),
                 value1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 value2 = c(2,3,4,5,6))
```

I want to `summarise` columns `value1` and `value2` based on the matched parts of column `name`**and** keep the unique values of the new column `author`. This code only does the summarising part but `author` is gone:

```
df %>%
  mutate(author = str_extract(name, "(?<=\\s)(?=.*\\.)[.\\w]+$"),
         name1 = trimws(str_remove(name, "(?<=\\s)(?=.*\\.)[.\\w]+$"))) %>%
  group_by(name1) %>%
  summarise(across(c(value1, value2), sum))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name1                     value1 value2
* <chr>                      <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Acer laurinum                  3      5
2 Acmella paniculata             3      4
3 Adinandra cf. integerrima      9     11
```

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name1                     value1 value2      author
* <chr>                      <dbl>  <dbl>       <chr>
1 Acer laurinum                  3      5       Hassk.
2 Acmella paniculata             3      4        <NA>
3 Adinandra cf. integerrima      9     11  T.Anderson
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `na.omit(author)[1]` to get 1st non NA value of `author` in the group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(author = str_extract(name, "(?<=\\s)(?=.*\\.)[.\\w]+$"),
         name1 = trimws(str_remove(name, "(?<=\\s)(?=.*\\.)[.\\w]+$"))) %>%
  group_by(name1) %>%
  summarise(across(c(value1, value2), sum), 
            author = na.omit(author)[1])

#  name1                     value1 value2 author    
#  <chr>                      <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     
#1 Acer laurinum                  3      5 Hassk.    
#2 Acmella paniculata             3      4 NA        
#3 Adinandra cf. integerrima      9     11 T.Anderson
```